# Why am I getting "Cannot convert error"?

Tags: c#

I have this code in a new class:

```
Object[] temp_arr = new Object[5];
                temp_arr[0] = csFiles;
                temp_arr[1] = mainUrl;
                temp_arr[2] = levels;
                temp_arr[3] = currentCrawlingSite;
                temp_arr[4] = sitesToCrawl;
```

The variables csFiles and currentCrawlingSite are both List<string>.

Then in the bottom I did:

```
public class WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler : EventArgs
{
    public List<string> csFiles { get; set; }
    public string mainUrl { get; set; }
    public int levels { get; set; }
    public List<string> currentCrawlingSite { get; set; }
}

protected void OnProgressEvent( Object[] some_params)
{
    if (ProgressEvent != null)
        ProgressEvent(this,
                      new WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler()
                      {
                          csFiles = some_params[0],
                          mainUrl = some_params[1],
                          levels = some_params[2],
                          currentCrawlingSite = some_params[3]
                      });
}
```

Now I'm getting an error on all the lines inside the new `WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler()` the same error for each line:

> *Error  2  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)*

But if I remove the line: `public List<string> currentCrawlingSite { get; set; }` and the line: `currentCrawlingSite = some_params[3]` there are no errors.

I don't get it. `csFiles` and `currentCrawlingSite` are both `List<string>` type variables. Why, when I add the `currentCrawlingSite`, am I getting the error/s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler does not and can not know that the first and forth element of the `Object`-array happens to be `List<string>`.

You have to cast them accordingly:

```
csFiles = (List<String>)some_params[0]
```

etc. or better, use an appropriate type to pass your data around instead of a simple `Object`-array if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that `OnProgressEvent` is sending you an `Object` array, so you're trying to assign an `Object` to `List<string>` type variable in that "culprit" line, thereby implicit invoking a cast operation. You should really do an explicit cast there to solve your problem.

The new and preferred syntax in C# is:

```
csFiles = some_params[0] as List<String>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you are assigning is a List<string> you need to cast it to this type:

```
new WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler()
{
    csFiles = (List<string>)some_params[0],
    mainUrl = some_params[1],
    levels = some_params[2],
    currentCrawlingSite = (List<string>)some_params[3]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strong typing protection. You should explicitly cast an object to `List<string>` to ensure that you don't just mix up different types at the compile time

```
csFiles = (List<string>)some_params[0]
```

You don't have an error on `mainUrl = some_params[1]` because every object have `ToString()` method and the default behavior is to call this method for implicit type convertion.

J. Richter writes in his book:

> For example, C# doesn’t require any special syntax to cast an object
>   to any of its base types, because casts to base types are considered
>   safe implicit conversions. However, C# does require the developer to
>   explicitly cast an object to any of its derived types since such a
>   cast could fail at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`currentCrawlingSite` is an instance of `List<string>`, `some_params` is an instance of `object` array.

You can't *implicitly* convert these two types. You have to use explicit conversation. You can use them like;

```
currentCrawlingSite = (List<string>)some_params[3];
```

is equal also

```
currentCrawlingSite = some_params[3] as List<string>;
```

You can read much more details from [`Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)